# java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[] org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss, sessionfactory

I have a problem with my jboss (6.4.5 eap) and hibernate (4.2.21).

> 1,112 instances of "org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl", loaded
>   by "" occupy 1,284,125,312 (62.84%) bytes. These
>   instances are referenced from one instance of
>   "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]", loaded by ""
>
> Keywords java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl

Below is an image.

[image]

Does anyone had/has similar problem?

I found https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8943 but is's a little bit different.

Comment: how many sessions are creating with Hibernate? is the number expected?

Comment: i guess 1,112 instances of "org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl"

Comment: I think your hibernate sessions are each caching data most likely.  You may want to try to disable caching.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: unfortunately not